# Ubiquitous HTML.DropDownListFor not selecting a default, even though I can query the selected value dynamically

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I have seen many a question on here where the dropdownlistfor html control is not showing the selected option.

My app is using view models and from what I have read on SO so far, in most cases, this is down to the fact that the variable types are different data types.

In my case, the dropdownlistfor is populating the list part of the dropdown, but not setting the current value.

In the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TypeCaption, Model.Types)
```

In the view model:

```
public MyData()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeCaption { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }     
}
```

Example data:

```
Id = 3762,  TypeCaption = "Option2", Reference = "Some value to be displayed"

IEnumerated<SelectListItem> Types 

Value  = "1",   Text = "Option1"
Value  = "2",   Text = "Option2"
Value  = "3",   Text = "Option3"
```

So I expecting

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TypeCaption, Model.Types)
```

To show the second SelectlistItem from the Types property, but it is showing me the first instead.

I have checked that the data types are the same by using

```
Model.Types.Where(x => x.Text == Model.TypeCaption).Select(x => x.Value)
```

which returns the correct answer: Value = "2"

So I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

**Updated**

Just tried Scrobi's answer and it made no difference.

Comment: Should it be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeCaption, Model.Types)`

Comment: Updated question with answer for Scrobi

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if you want to call it that.......

Ok, the solution was to change the way that I populated the SelectListitem array. Originally I was using:

```
IEnumerated<SelectListItem> Types 
Value  = "1",   Text = "Option1"
Value  = "2",   Text = "Option2"
Value  = "3",   Text = "Option3"
```

I changed this to be:

```
IEnumerated<SelectListItem> Types 
Text = "Option1"
Text = "Option2"
Text = "Option3"
```

This now works.